# Get model in the controller

Tags: binding, model, controller, sapui5

In a SAPUI5 application, I'm using the function onBeforeRendering in the controller to update the view right before it's shown.

In the function, I tried to get the path using:

```
var sPath = evt.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath();
```

But it's telling me that evt.getSource().getBindingContext() is undefined.
But I need it to get the model.

Usually I get the model like this:

```
var data = this.getView().getModel().getData(sPath);
```

But now I can't because I can't get the path.

With:

```
var data = this.getView().getModel().getData();
```

It's not working either (null).

However, in the console I'm able to get the model using:

```
var data = this.getView().getModel().oData;
```

But, I know it's not a good thing to do ...

Comment: We need to see more of the code in order to help you. Can you show us how did you set the model to the view? [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

The following items come to mind after reading your question. For more accurate answer, we need to see your code.

1. Check that you try to call the model `this.getView().getModel().getData();` **after** you define it.

For example, if you set the model in a success function of ajax call, the call may not be finished when you get to the line where you try to call it.

2. Check that the model doesn't have a name. If it does, call it by `this.getView().getModel("model's-name-here").getData();`
3. In line

   `var sPath = evt.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath();`

you try to get a model from an event (`evt`). Check that you have that event at all in `onBeforeRendering` function.

4. Check that you attached the model you call to the view (`this.getView().setModel(oModel)`) and not to the core (`sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel)`).